# Cartoon with two boys and a girl fighting by transforming into monsters and capturing the defeated monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

A cartoon with two boys and a girl fighting by transforming into monsters and capturing the defeated monsters.

If I remember correctly, the guy had a fire monster and his friend (the other guy) had an ice monster. Iforgot what the girl had.

I remember at the end they had a tournament at the end with the bad guys and it was shown that the main character's dad was still alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess *Redakai: Conquer the Kairu* (2011).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series)):

> The series revolves around Ky, a 15-year-old student of ancient martial arts, who embarks on an epic quest to find the Kairu, a primordial alien energy source. Aided by his friends Maya and Boomer, Ky travels the world searching for the Kairu while attempting to make sure that his extraterrestrial teenage alien adversaries don’t find it first.

...

> Ky Stax is the charismatic leader of Team Stax and the heir to his father Connor's legacy. After displaying a gift for the Art of Kairu, Ky was sent by his father to train under the wise Boaddai. His destiny would be ultimately be revealed following the Great Cataclysm – to continue his father's legacy and protect Kairu from Lokar. Ky fiercely believes his father survived the Great Cataclysm and is determined to discover the truth behind Connor's disappearance.

Wikipedia mentions him being affiliated with plasma abilities, and his friend Boomer using "Freeze Rays".

[The wikia](https://redapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Connor_Stax) has several appearances of the father, who's not that dead after all:

> In The Return of Connor Stax, he was seen alive inside a block of ice but was found and released by an Inuit. He became friends with the man and his son and also helped out Team Stax against the Battacor from the distance.
>
> He also appeared in the episode Clash of the Kairu Warriors: Part I where he was spying in Lokar's lair.
>
> He appeared again in Clash of the Kairu Warriors: Part II

---

Found a bit by habit, the "teenagers transform into monsters cartoon" identification questions usually end up being *Chaotic*, *Kaijudo* or *Redakai*.